# Spark on Kubernetes processing in Azure Redis 250 milion records from parquet files - how to configure it correctly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm running Spark drivers on AKS cluster pods. Spark job is to pick up 250 milions of records from Azure Storage from given location >> create dataframe from them >> select one column >> create a list by Pandas toList() method >> take list and check existance of each record from list in Redis DB >> return results to driver for further processing

Provided data is splitted in 50 parquet files, each one containing 5 milion of records.

DAG from job failing:

[DAG from job failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Arj5.png)

Stage failing:

[Stage failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwma8.png)

Because of node specification I have limited compute power. For now, this is configuration of Spark, that I have:

```
    spark.driver.maxResultSize=5G
    spark.driver.memory=10G
    spark.executor.memory=8G
    spark.executor.cores=3
    spark.driver.cores=3
    spark.executor.instances=10
    spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic
    spark.driver.memoryOverhead=0
    spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2G
```

and defined in code:

```
spark_conf.set('spark.default.parallelism', num_executors * executor_cores)
spark_conf.set('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', num_executors * executor_cores)
```

Error received on driver Pod:

```
[Stage 1:======================================================>  (38 + 2) / 40]

[Stage 1:=======================================================> (39 + 1) / 40]

[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 24) / 30]

[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 25) / 30]

[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 27) / 30]

[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 28) / 30]

[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 29) / 30]

[Stage 2:>                                                        (0 + 30) / 30]

[Stage 2:=>                                                       (1 + 29) / 30]
[2022-12-28 15:28:45,156: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Exception while sending command.
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00 Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py", line 241, in _collect_as_arrow
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00     results = list(_load_from_socket((port, auth_secret), ArrowCollectSerializer()))
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py", line 60, in load_stream
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00     for batch in self.serializer.load_stream(stream):
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00   File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/serializers.py", line 99, in load_stream
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00     for batch in reader:
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00   File "pyarrow/ipc.pxi", line 436, in __iter__
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00   File "pyarrow/ipc.pxi", line 468, in pyarrow.lib.RecordBatchReader.read_next_batch
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00   File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 99, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
2022-12-28T16:28:45+01:00 OSError: Expected to be able to read 449936 bytes for message body, got 442208
```

Running different Spark configuration is leading to different errors, but each of them seems to be caused by insuffitient memory (SIGKILL, Java Heap Size, etc.)

Is Pandas method bottlenecking somehow whole process by its usage of memory here?
I was able to run such process for 1,5 milion records - can you advise me how to configure and tune up Spark to process the amount of data mentioned in the beginning? - is it possible to do so with these resources available?